# When is a mapping the proximity operator of some convex function?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, signal-processing, image-processing

Sorry for cross-posting from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/239134/78539). It's been a few days and the question hasn't received any attention there.

So, is there a characterization of mappings $p : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ which are proximity operators ([in the sense of Moreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_method#Definition)) of l.s.c (extended) real-valued functions ?
That is, given $p : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, under what sufficient conditions does there exist an extended-valued l.s.c  convex function $g:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ such that
$$p(x) \equiv \mathrm{prox}_g(x) := \underset{z \in \mathbb R^n}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}\|z-x\|_2^2 + g(z) \;?$$

**N.B:** Of course it's necessary that $p$ be firmly-nonexpansive, and have other classical properties of prox operators.

**Motivation:** In regularization techniques for signal / image processing, one usually proposes to minimize an energy of the form $f(x) + g(x)$, where $x=x^*$ is the image to be recovered from noisy / corrupted measures, $f(x)$ is a *data fidelity* term and measures the "fit" of the model, while $g(x)$ is a regularization term that imposes some structural constraints. For example, one can take $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|y-Ax\|_2^2$, under a additve Gaussian-noise assumption, where $y$ is the observed image and $A$ is a sensing linear operator, so that $y \approx Ax + \text{ noise}$, etc., etc.

A brilliant idea that has been proposed in [*Social Sparsity!*](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00691774v1/document) is to impose the penalty $g$ only implicitly, by instead constructing its proximal operator $p(x)$, i.e by stating the intended shrinkage action of $g$ on the model coefficients $x_j$.

For a concrete example, think of a (fictional) world in which we didn't know about the $\ell_1$ norm, but instead decided to invent the Lasso by stating that the prox of the (unknown) $\ell_1$ penalty should shrink the coefficients according to the *soft-thresholder*
$$(p(x))_j = st_{\lambda}(x_j) = sign(x_j)(|x_j| - \lambda)_+,$$

[image]

where $\lambda > 0$ is a regularization parameter and $sign(x_j): = -sign(-x_j) = 1$ if $ x_j > 0$ and $0$ else. Note that the above prox would correspond to a penalty $g(x) = \lambda \|x\|_1$, and acts component-wise only because we're assuming (in this example) a separable penalty.

The question is then: *How to show that $st_{\lambda}$ actually corresponds to the proximal operator of some penalty function.*

### Update

I've accepted an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/239618/78539), under the original MO post.

Comment: I think we know why it hasn't received attention at MO :-) Potential paper topic? :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant: haha, yeah, u're right; it's kind of an important step for a potential paper topic  ;)

Comment: I've update the question to emphasize the motivations.

Comment: Why don't you paste the answers as a Wiki answer here? To make the question closed here.

Answer (score 0):

One characterization is in the Moreau paper cited in the MO answer. Here is another characterization, thanks to Combettes and Pesquet's SIOPT paper in 2007.

> $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a proximal operator if and only if it is nonexpansive and increasing.

My understanding is that this is an open question for greater $n$.